# access is denied at form_open

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?=form_open('pages/reset')>
</form>
```

I have a function reset in the main class that is to load the reset_view.php file

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controler
{
   .....
   public function reset()
   {
      $this->load->view("pages/reset_view");
   }
}
?>
```

reset_view.php is stored inside application/views/pages
Could someone tell me what is going on, why I get an error at form_open line ? Thank you.

I have got an error page

> Access forbidden!   You don't have permission to access the requested
>   object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403

Comment: I edit to clearify it better.

Answer (score 0):

you might have forgotten to include form helper. check in controller file make sure you have loaded form helper.

this is one possible problem I can find out. hope it will work for you